# PHP - How to get all the calling class

Tags: php

How to get all the calling class?

I tried:

```
function __autoload ($class){
require $class;
debug_print_backtrace();
}

$obj1 = new Foo();
$obj2 = new Foo();
$obj3 = new Foo();
```

Result:

```
#0 __autoload(Foo) called at [/var/www/index.php:8]
```

But I need result - I need to list all calls :(

```
#0 __autoload(Foo) called at [/var/www/index.php:8]
#0 __autoload(Foo) called at [/var/www/index.php:9]
#0 __autoload(Foo) called at [/var/www/index.php:10]
```

Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: Autoload runs only __once__ for you class `Foo`.

Comment: You can use **__construct** method to count your calls

Comment: There must be a better solution, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not printing the backtrace on *calling* the class, you are printing it on *loading* it. And you only need to load it once (the first time it is called).

If you want to show it on calling, you need to add it to the constructor of your `Foo` class, like

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         // your other construct code
         // if you didn't have one, maybe a parent::__construct()
         debug_print_backtrace();
    }
}
```

Now you get the backtrace everytime you make an instance of the class.

This does mean you have to do it in every class, which can be tedious, but it's the best you can do. Maybe there is a different solution to what you are trying to do, but you have not added the reason for this requirement, so it's hard to find that other solution :)

Comment: I already wrote it, I need to capture all called classes. without modifying each class. ;)